# 'as' and 'such as' and their differences

Tags: difference, usage

I read this in [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/as?s=t):

> **as** can be used to mean **for example ; for instance**
>   *Some flowers, as the rose, require special care.*

How this use of  "as" is different from "such as" ?

Answer (score 1):

In this context, the meaning is the same, however I can't imagine a native English speaker using **as** in this way. When I read this sentence, I thought at first that a word (such) had been accidentally omitted.

It would have been much clearer to write

> Some flowers, *such* as the rose, require special care.